# CSS Selected 2nd child starting with 2nd

Tags: css, css-selectors

ist there a way to target every second element with `:nth-child(2n)` starting on the second ?

For exemple:

```
<ul>
  <li>do not target</li>
  <li>do not target</li>
  <li>target</li>
  <li>do not target</li>
  <li>target</li>
  <li>do not target</li>
  <li>target</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering the given markup, it seems that you want it to start from the *third* `<li>` child **not** the *second* one, therefore you use the following:

```
:nth-child(2n+3)
```

```
<ul>
  <li>do not target</li> <!-- 1st -->
  <li>do not target</li> <!-- 2nd -->
  <li>target</li>        <!-- 3rd -->
  <li>do not target</li>
  <li>target</li>
  <li>do not target</li>
  <li>target</li>
</ul>
```

Also if you really want it to start from the second child, the effect of `:nth-child(2n)` and `:nth-child(2n+2)` would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hashem's answer is good, but I feel like `:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child)` is more clear about what is going on.

.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.

Comment: @Paulie_D fair enough :)